# Best way to generate records for each day for the week for the whole year MySQL

Tags: mysql

As the title says. I don't know the best way to do this and it would be a tedious to hard code it into my database.

I have a booking system that allows the user to book every sunday, tuesday, wednesday and Friday every week, from months between May and October. Any thoughts are appreciated as I literally have no clue other than entering them in one by one.

Comment: Have you tried reading about MySql events https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and thank you for linking that other question. I couldn't find that one and it matches my need well. I'll remove my question.